# ACF/PACF of my residuals from the cointegration model shows a perfect 1-lag autocorrelation?

Tags: residuals, cointegration, acf-pacf

I'm performing a cointegration test + OLS regression on 2 assets' prices. If I check the correlogram of the model residuals (training set, but also happens with the test set residuals) it looks like there is a perfect 1-lag autocorrelation in the residuals:
[image]

[image]

And this is what my residuals look like:

[image]

What can be the cause of this? I'm assuming something must be wrong, but no idea what.

Comment: Is the cointegration of order 1?

Comment: I take the first difference (I(1)) of the log prices at time t always (et - mean = P1t * coeff - P2t), I never use any kind of lag

Comment: So you have a regression of $\ln(Y_t)$ on $\ln(X_t)$ where $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are prices? And the residuals looks like in the plot? Then your time series might not be cointegrated.